# Web Deployment Project on VS2019

Tags: asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2019, web-deployment-project

I've created a blank solution in VS2019. Using the option "add existing web site" I've added a website to the solution which was built in VS2010. Normally, after that, I was used to add a Web Deployment Project to the solution, to compile all the code in one dll, and upload the result to the web server.
But this kind of project does not seem to be compatible anymore with the newer versions of VS.

Is there any way to get a similar compiled result in VS2019?

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative.

It is to convert the [asp.net web site] to an [asp.net application]. The asp.net application has a publish feature, which can be used to generate an output folder with the compiled application inside, with the aspx pages and a single dll.

I suggest to follow the steps described here to convert the asp.net web site to asp.net application:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa983476(v=vs.140)